# Bootstrap 3 navbar-toggle opening at 90% width then sliding right to fill screen?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a navbar-toggle menu that, when opened, opens at what looks like 90% width then slides right to fill the screen!  I cannot work out what the issue is here: http://www.bootply.com/ZanQBWTECu

Also in desktop view in the same example I have a nav-pills nav-justified menu that, when you hover over a button, increases in height to give the impression of a button moving down however when I click on one of the submenu options it jumps back to its original height.

How do I get the button to remain at the increased width?

Comment: i dont even see it open?

Comment: Sorry, updated now...http://www.bootply.com/ZanQBWTECu

Comment: Oh, this toggle menu also doesn't work on any iPhone or iPad but does work on android and windows phone.  Weird.

Comment: i got it - here is the problem

Answer (score 1):

remove

```
.nav {
letter-spacing: 1px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 20;
}
```

replace with

```
#rickwoodcollapse {
width:100%;
padding:0;
}
```

here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/4PGsLHNM5C) -

Comment: That fixes it so is this a problem with position: absolute or z-index: 20?

Comment: ya no need to absolute position- close q if its fixed